# Determine how much each CPU cycle consumes battery life

Tags: android, performance, cpu, cpu-usage, batterylevel

For an Android application I need to know how much each CPU cycle consumes battery life.
I would like to know how much energy that function used, is there a way to determine that?

Comment: Contact chuck norris.

Comment: :) thanks man , but seriously how can each function in a certain algorithm affects the battery , as long as the CPU process more instructions the battery drain is more , so there is a kind of relation between CPU cycles and battery consumption , any ideas